# Can't add record to database PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Hi I am creating a payment method for a website but I've got one stumbling block.

I have a HTML form which looks like this:

```
    <form method="post" action="member/payment.php">
                    <div class="field">
                      <label class="label">Voor- en achternaam</label>
                      <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" name="nameField" id="nameField" type="text" placeholder="Vul hier uw naam in">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                      <label class="label">Email</label>
                      <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                        <input class="input" name="mailField" id="mailField" type="email" placeholder="voorbeeld@voorbeeld.nl">
                        <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                          <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                          <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <!-- <p class="help is-danger">This email is invalid</p> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                      <label class="label">Gebruikersnaam</label>
                      <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" type="text" name="usernameField" id="usernameField" placeholder="Vul hier uw gebruikersnaam in">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">Wachtwoord</label>
                  <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="password" name="passwordField" id="passwordField" placeholder="Vul hier uw wachtwoord in">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                  <label class="label">Wachtwoord</label>
                  <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="password" name="passwordField2" id="passwordField2" placeholder="Vul hier uw wachtwoord nogmaals in">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <center><a class="button is-red is-large" type="submit" href="member/payment.php">Betalen</a></center>
              </form>
```

Now once I click the `submit` button I want is to go to this file:

```
      <?php

      use PayPal\Api\Payer;
      use PayPal\Api\Details;
      use PayPal\Api\Amount;
      use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
      use PayPal\Api\Payment;
      use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
      use PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionExeption;

      require '../src/start.php';

      $payer = new Payer();
      $details = new Details();
      $amount = new Amount();
      $transaction = new Transaction();
      $payment = new Payment();
      $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();


      //Payer
      $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

      // Details
      $details->setShipping('0.00')
        ->setTax('2.60')
        ->setSubtotal('12.40');

      $amount->setCurrency('EUR')
        ->setTotal('15.00')
        ->setDetails($details);

      //Transaction
      $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setDescription('Een licensie voor kilometro');

      //Payment
      $payment->setIntent('sale')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

      //RedirectUrls
      $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('http://localhost/payments/paypal/pay.php?approved=true')
        ->setCancelUrl('http://localhost/payments/paypal/pay.php?approved=false');

      $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

      try{
        $payment->create($api);

        //Generate/store hash
        $hash = md5($payment->getId());
        $_SESSION['paypal_hash'] = $hash;

        //Prepare and execute transaction storage
        $store = $db->prepare("
          INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, payment_id, hash, complete)
          VALUES (:user_id, :payment_id, :hash, 0)
        ");

        $store->execute([
          'user_id'=> $_SESSION['user_id'],
          'payment_id' => $payment->getId(),
          'hash' => $hash
        ]);

      } catch(PPConnectionExeption $e){
        //Perhaps log an error
        header('Location: ../paypal/error.php');
      }

      foreach ($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
        # code...
        if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url'){
          $redirectUrls = $link->getHref();
        }
      }

      header('Location: ' . $redirectUrls);

       ?>
```

(which is `payment.php`).

This file requires this file:

```
      <?php

      use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
      use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

      session_start();

      $_SESSION['user_id'];
      $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['nameField'];
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['usernameField'];
      $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['mailField'];
      $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['passwordField'];
      $_SESSION['password2'] = $_POST['passwordField2'];


      require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

      $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kilometers', 'root', '');

      $addMember = $db->prepare("
        INSERT INTO transactions (username, password, naam, email, license)
        VALUES(:username, :password, :name, :email, 0)
      ");

      $addMember->execute([
        'username' => $_SESSION['username'],
        'password' => $_SESSION['password'],
        'name' => $_SESSION['name'],
        'email' => $_SESSION['email']
      ]);


      //API
      $api = new ApiContext(
        new OAuthTokenCredential(
            '-',
            '-'
          )
      );

      $api->setConfig([
        'mode' => 'sandbox',
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
        'log.LogEnabled' => false,
        'log.FileName' => '',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE',
        'validation.level' => 'log'
      ]);



      $getUser = $db->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM customers
        WHERE name = :name
          AND username = :username
          AND password = :password
          AND email = :email
      ");


      $getUser->execute([
        'username' => $_SESSION['username'],
        'password' => $_SESSION['password'],
        'name' => $_SESSION['name'],
        'email' => $_SESSION['email']
      ]);

      $user = $getUser->fetchObject();
      $_SESSION['user_id']=$user->id;
      //}
      ?>
```

(`start.php`)

Now if I submit the form it works but it doesn't add a member in the database.. As it is supposed to do at `line 20-30` of `start.php`. What could be the problem?

Comment: post your code *in* the question; the question doesn't hold water when using external resources for us to fetch that code; I certainly won't.

Comment: Okay I changed it

Comment: consult https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php apply that to your code and see if there is anything that comes back.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner as far as I can see right now I am not getting any error but I have debuged a bit more and it turns out that the `$_POST` info is not geeting to my script